# RedirectToAction not finding Controller after migration from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` from within an area, which should redirect to the home controller which is not within an area. I am redirecting from the `Auth` area.

My `Startup` endpoint config is as follows:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "MyArea",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Auth",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Login}/{action=Login}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Auth",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Register}/{action=Register}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Auth",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Logout}/{action=Logout}");
        });
```

After the Redirect call the controller is not reached. This use to work in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC.

Here is the MVC routing that worked

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default Areas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Auth",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Login}/{action=Login}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Auth",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Register}/{action=Register}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Auth",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Logout}/{action=Logout}");
```

---

I have found that using this `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });` works when I need to route to location outside of the Area's.

I do not understand why asp.net 3.1 is not finding the routing rule where the area is not defined `pattern:"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` , when redirecting without an explicit area defined `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`.

Comment: Did you look at the migration guide? a lot of things changed in v3  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code

Comment: I do not understand the problem... Seems like you already solved it.

Comment: I have a workaround yes, but would like to find the document or reason for this.